# WCF NetTcpBinding file transfer

Tags: wcf, file, transfer, nettcpbinding

I am using wcf nettcpbinding for transfering files (with streaming), and I can't transfer files larger than 650 MB. This is the exception: "The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '19:59:59.9350000'."

I think it's not a timeout problem, they are set to hours. Some ideas to solve this??

Comment: Please share the pertinent config section details.  What do you have on client and server for max received and sent file sizes?

Comment: Also, try enabling tracing on the client and server to see if there is an exception logged which can give more information about this problem.

Answer (score 3):

The default max received message size is 65536 bytes, if someone has increased this value just by adding zeros, 655360000 it could explain the 650 MB limit.

Also see: http://setus.blogspot.com/2009/01/how-to-sendreceive-large-data-in-wcf.html